# nano: How to unset option from .nanorc?

Tags: nano

I have in my `.nanorc`

```
set tabstospaces
```

This correponds to the commandline option `-E`, and is usually the setting I want to achieve. In rare cases, however, I want to edit a file by inserting literal tabs, and this default setting gets in my way. How can I unset this option for a single execution of nano, without temporarily commenting out?

I tried to invoke nano with

```
nano +E ....
```

but this still inserts spaces instead of literal tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options can be toggled on the fly by certain keystrokes. Check help while in `nano` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to enter, <kbd>Q</kbd> to leave); or invoke `info nano` in a shell and read about *Feature Toggles*.

The option in question is toggled by <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (i.e. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>).